# Calculate percentage of rows with a column above a certain value Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a sample of a large dataset as below

[image]

I would like to get the percentage of the count of number of rows with a value above 30 which would give me an output as below

[image]

How would I go about achieving this with pandas. I have gotten to this last point of processing my data and a bit stuck with this

Comment: Percentage i.e 3 out of 5 are above 30 hence 60%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare values for greater like `30` with aggregate `mean`:

```
df = (df.B > 30).groupby(df['A']).mean().mul(100).reset_index(name='C')
print (df)
   A     C
0  r  60.0
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(C = df.B > 30).groupby('A')['C'].mean().mul(100).reset_index()
```